Quarkus scheduler is shared amongst azure multiple instances?
I have Quarkus Java app which uses scheduler and runs every 15 second inside the scheduler reading a query and updating etc…my concern is I want to understand if this scheduler is shared amongst instances or each instance create its own scheduler so if this is the case it might run into concurrency issues
I thought of azure storage blob which says that only one instance at a time takes a lock so there is only one scheduler at e time either on first instance or second but not on both, but this is the case if quarks scheduler is really created separately on both two instances?

Each instance has its own scheduler. Thus, mutliple instances run the scheduled taks independently of each other. If we want a clustered solution (i.e. only one instance should run the scheduled task), we need some kind of synchronization, e.g. through quarkus-quartz (quarkus.io)

@Turing85 thanks for your answer and I also was thinking maybe I could add pessimtic write to the get query inside the scheduler?
